# Xaml c# datatable binding textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind the data of a datatable to a textbox.
It works fine, but it displays only the last row of the datatable.
Is it possible to display all rows of the datatable?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="messenger.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="203" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="conversationInput" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="491" Margin="12,3,0,0" IsReadOnly="True">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{0} : {1}">
                <Binding Path="date" />
                <Binding Path="message" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
    public DataTable loadConversation()
    {
        DataTable conversation = new DataTable();
        string loadMessages = "select message, date from Messages where userID=1";
        ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(loadMessages, connection);
        ad.Fill(conversation);
        return conversation;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        conversationInput.DataContext = loadConversation().DefaultView;
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
Fluxxi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is but you will need to use some kind of repeater control - like a [DataGrid](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) or a [ListView](http://tech.pro/tutorial/742/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1).

Answer (score 0):

This how `TextBox` is designed. You should use a `ListBox` (or similar) control instead.